# Is it possible to use Gradle to build an Android native exeutable?

Tags: android, gradle, gnu-make

I have an `Android.mk` and `Application.mk` build file. I think the build system is called GNU make. I am then calling `ndk-build` to build the native executable.

I am building a normal ELF executable just like `/system/bin/echo` for example.

The actual command which builds the executable is:

```
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

I think the rest of the file contents are irrelevant to this question because I only want to know if it's possible to switch to a Gradle build file instead of `.mk` files?